# Choosing data structure

Tags: javascript, java

I'm coding in some little cricket game. In cricket 11 players there in each team so I need to store their personal score and balls played.

So which data structure is useful to store batesmen name along with personal score and balls played.
Ex:
Virat . RunsScored = 34
Vir at. Ballsplayed    = 15

Comment: JavaScript is not Java.

Comment: I know that java is not a java script.

Comment: I don't think you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to use builtin types - a HashMap of HashMaps could be a good way, maintaining quick read access times.

In Java,

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> playerMap = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Then, based on your given example:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> entry = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
entry.put("runsScored", 34);
entry.put("ballsPlayed", 15);

playerMap.put("Virat", entry);
```

To retrieve Virat's runsScored, for example:

```
playerMap.get("Virat").get("runsScored");
```

Lookup time would be in O(1), versus O(n) with an array - if performance is an issue.

You could also create two separate hashmaps - one for the player's runsScored, and one for ballsPlayed. This might be slightly less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a Player object that has class variables for runsScored, ballsPlayed, etc. Then in your main you can have an array of those players:

```
Player[] myTeam = new Player[11];

class Player {
    private String name;
    private int runsScored = 0;
    private int ballsPlayed = 0;

    Player (String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // ...etc...
}
```